# Error al llamar al webservice SII (Suministro Inmediato de Información) de la AEAT

Tags: c#, aeat-sii

Al hacer la llamada a un método del webservice de la AEAT me da el siguiente error:

> The content type text/html of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="es-ES">
<head>
    <title>Agencia Tributaria - Se ha producido un error</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">       
<link href="https://www.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/css/xzhtcs04.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
><script type="text/javascript"> 
        function toggle()
        {
            var o=document.getElementById("AEAT_errores_tecnicos");
            o.style.display=(o.style.display=='' || o.style.display=='none')?'block':'none';
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
><div id="body">      
    <div id="header">
    <div id="AEAT_header">
      <div id="topIzquierda">
        <div id="logoAEAT">
            <ul>
                <li><a target="_self" href="https://www.agenciatributaria.gob.es"><span class="logoGobierno"></span></a>
                </li>
                <li><a target="_self" href="http://www.agenciatributaria.es"><span class="logoAEAT"></span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>           
        </div>    
     '.
```

La llamada al ws la estoy haciendo así:

```
SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas FacturaEmitida = ObtenerObjetoEnvioFacturaEmitida();


siiSOAPClient wsSuministroFacturasEmitidas = new siiSOAPClient();

wsSuministroFacturasEmitidas.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = certificadoObtenido;
wsSuministroFacturasEmitidas.ClientCredentials.UseIdentityConfiguration = true;
RespuestaLRFEmitidasType resultadoEnvioFactura = wsSuministroFacturasEmitidas.SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas(FacturaEmitida);
```

el objeto que le paso al webservice es este:

```
private static SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas ObtenerObjetoEnvioFacturaEmitida()
{
    //ObjetoGeneral Factura Emitida
    SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas FacturaEmitida = new SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas();

    //ObjetoCabecera Factura Emitida -> dentro lleva un objeto Titular
    CabeceraSii CabeceraFacutraEmitida = new CabeceraSii();
    //Objeto Titular
    PersonaFisicaJuridicaESType TitularFacturaEmitida = new PersonaFisicaJuridicaESType();
    //Facturas Emitidas
    List<LRfacturasEmitidasType> FacturasEmitidas = new List<LRfacturasEmitidasType>();
    //Periodo Impositivo
    RegistroSiiPeriodoImpositivo itemPeriodoImpositivo = new RegistroSiiPeriodoImpositivo();
    //Objeto Item para la factura
    LRfacturasEmitidasType ItemFactura = new LRfacturasEmitidasType();
    //Objeto IdFactura -> Contiene un objeto de tipo IDEmisora
    IDFacturaExpedidaType IdFactura = new IDFacturaExpedidaType();
    //Objeto IDEmisora
    IDFacturaExpedidaTypeIDEmisorFactura IDEmisora = new IDFacturaExpedidaTypeIDEmisorFactura();
    //Objeto Factura ExpedidaType
    FacturaExpedidaType FacturaExpedida = new FacturaExpedidaType();
    //Objeto FacturasAgrupadas
    IDFacturaARType[] FacturasAgrupadas = new IDFacturaARType[1];
    IDFacturaARType ElementoFacturasAgrupadas = new IDFacturaARType();

    //Objeto Facturas Rectificativas
    IDFacturaARType[] FacturasRectificativas = new IDFacturaARType[1];
    IDFacturaARType ElementoFacturasRectificativas = new IDFacturaARType();

    //ObjetoImporteRectificacion
    DesgloseRectificacionType ImporteRectificacion = new DesgloseRectificacionType();

    //Objeto DatosInmueble
    DatosInmuebleType[] DatosInmueble = new DatosInmuebleType[1];
    DatosInmuebleType ElementoDatosInmueble = new DatosInmuebleType();

    //Objeto Contraparte
    PersonaFisicaJuridicaType Contraparte = new PersonaFisicaJuridicaType();
    //Ojeto TipoDesglose
    FacturaExpedidaTypeTipoDesglose TipoDesglose = new FacturaExpedidaTypeTipoDesglose();

    CabeceraFacutraEmitida.IDVersionSii = VersionSiiType.Item06;
    CabeceraFacutraEmitida.TipoComunicacion = ClaveTipoComunicacionType.A0;
    CabeceraFacutraEmitida.Titular = TitularFacturaEmitida; 

    //Titular de la cabecera de la factura
    TitularFacturaEmitida.NIF = "AAAA";
    TitularFacturaEmitida.NombreRazon = "prueba";
    TitularFacturaEmitida.NIFRepresentante = "RepresentanteXXXXX";

    FacturaEmitida.Cabecera = CabeceraFacutraEmitida; //Añadida cabecera de la factura

    itemPeriodoImpositivo.Periodo = TipoPeriodoType.Item01;
    itemPeriodoImpositivo.Ejercicio = "2015";
    ItemFactura.PeriodoImpositivo = itemPeriodoImpositivo;

    IDEmisora.NIF = "A84532501";
    IdFactura.NumSerieFacturaEmisor = "01";
    IdFactura.NumSerieFacturaEmisorResumenFin = "01";
    IdFactura.FechaExpedicionFacturaEmisor = "15-01-2015";
    IdFactura.IDEmisorFactura = IDEmisora;

    ItemFactura.IDFactura = IdFactura;

    FacturaExpedida.TipoFactura = ClaveTipoFacturaType.F1;
    FacturaExpedida.TipoRectificativa = ClaveTipoRectificativaType.I;
        FacturaExpedida.FechaOperacion = "15-01-2015";
    FacturaExpedida.ClaveRegimenEspecialOTrascendencia = IdOperacionesTrascendenciaTributariaType.Item01;
    FacturaExpedida.ImporteTotal = "26.70";
    FacturaExpedida.BaseImponibleACoste = "526";
    FacturaExpedida.DescripcionOperacion = "CompraXXXXXXX";
    FacturaExpedida.ImporteTransmisionSujetoAIVA = "Importe";
    FacturaExpedida.VariosDestinatarios = VariosDestinatariosType.N;
    FacturaExpedida.EmitidaPorTerceros = EmitidaPorTercerosType.N;
    FacturaExpedida.Cupon = CuponType.N;

    ElementoFacturasAgrupadas.NumSerieFacturaEmisor = "SERIE";
    ElementoFacturasAgrupadas.FechaExpedicionFacturaEmisor = "15-01-2015";
    FacturasAgrupadas[0] = ElementoFacturasAgrupadas;
    FacturaExpedida.FacturasAgrupadas = FacturasAgrupadas;

    ItemFactura.FacturaExpedida = FacturaExpedida;

    ElementoFacturasRectificativas.NumSerieFacturaEmisor = "SERIE";
    ElementoFacturasRectificativas.FechaExpedicionFacturaEmisor = "15-01-2015";
    FacturasRectificativas[0] = ElementoFacturasRectificativas;
    FacturaExpedida.FacturasRectificadas = FacturasRectificativas;

    ImporteRectificacion.BaseRectificada = "BASE";
    ImporteRectificacion.CuotaRecargoRectificado = "Cuota";
    ImporteRectificacion.CuotaRectificada = "Cuota";
    FacturaExpedida.ImporteRectificacion = ImporteRectificacion;

    ElementoDatosInmueble.SituacionInmueble = SituacionInmuebleType.Item1;
    ElementoDatosInmueble.ReferenciaCatastral = "Ref";

    DatosInmueble[0] = ElementoDatosInmueble;
    FacturaExpedida.DatosInmueble = DatosInmueble;

    Contraparte.NombreRazon = "EMPRESAYYYYYYYY";
    Contraparte.NIFRepresentante = "NIF";
    Contraparte.Item = "Item";
    FacturaExpedida.Contraparte = Contraparte;

    //((SuministroFactEmitidas.TipoSinDesgloseType)oSfe.RegistroLRFacturasEmitidas(0).FacturaExpedida.TipoDesglose.Item).Sujeta == new SuministroFactEmitidas.SujetaType()
    //TipoDesglose.Item = "";
    //TipoDesglose.Item
    //FacturaExpedida.TipoDesglose = TipoDesglose;

    //XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas));
    //using(TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Xml.xml"))
    //{
    //    serializer.Serialize(writer, FacturaEmitida);
    //}

    return FacturaEmitida;
}
```

Y la configuración del app.config del webservice es esta

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="siiBinding">
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
        <customBinding>
            <binding name="siiBinding">
                <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
                <httpsTransport />
            </binding>
        </customBinding>
    </bindings>

    <!-- Web Services AEAT -->
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://www7.aeat.es/wlpl/SSII-FACT/ws/fe/SiiFactFEV1SOAP"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="siiBinding"
            contract="SuministroFactEmitidas.siiSOAP" name="SuministroFactEmitidasPruebas" />
    </client>
    <!-- Fin Web Service AEAT -->

</system.serviceModel>
```

¿Alguien podría saber qué es lo que pasa?

Comment: Perdona @RandallSandoval, pero el titulo era correcto.SII significa "Suministro Inmediato de Informacion", es un servicio de la agencia tributaria española

Comment: @Pikoh yo también pensé que era IIS, en este caso considero que lo mejor sería poner el nombre completo  "*Suministro Inmediato de Informacion*" para no dejar lugar a dudas y no caer en suposiciones :)

Comment: Tienes razón @Flxtr. Ahora debería quedar mas claro :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema lo tienes en tu endpoint. Verás,

- Para Emitidas:

  ```
  https://www7.aeat.es/wlpl/SSII-FACT/ws/fe/SiiFactFEV1SOAP
  ```
- Para Recibidas:

  ```
  https://www7.aeat.es/wlpl/SSII-FACT/ws/fr/SiiFactFEV1SOAP
  ```

A mí me pasó lo mismo y casi me vuelvo loca y sólo tienes que cambiar **`fe`** por **`fr`**.

Comment: Hola, en este caso la prueba que estoy haciendo es sobre facturas emitidas por lo que supuestamente la url debería de estar bien...

Comment: ¿has probado a validar el esquema subiéndolo directamente a la web de pruebas? Para ir descartando posibles errores

Comment: Vale ya no me sale este error era un problema con el certificado. ¡¡Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Sugerencia: Dejen de poner a mano las URLs de endpoint de los servicios. Paso 1) Leer el XML fichero de definición y extraer los puertos en una lista. Paso 2) Sacar la URL del puerto dependiendo  al entorno al que se quiera conectar. ¿Por qué? Pues creo que SII podría cambiar esas URLs en cualquier momento, pero si las sacamos de la URL de WSDL del servicio en vez de ponerlas hardcoded será mejor y porque también es más práctico. Más info y sobretodo si trabajas con PHP en el ebook http://www.aeatsiidesarrolladores.es/

Answer (score 0):

Solucioné el error que te daba al principio añadiendole el certificado.

> The content type text/html of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were:

Ahora me da el siguiente error:

> No se pudo establecer un canal seguro para SSL/TLS con la autoridad 'http://www7.aeat.es'

---

He leído por ahí como hacer que nos comuniquemos por *SSL/TLS* haciendo una "trampa". El código quedaría:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate);
System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
binding.Name = "siiBinding";
binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;

FacturasEmitidas.siiSOAPClient Servicio = new FacturasEmitidas.siiSOAPClient("SuministroFactEmitidasPruebas", new EndpointAddress("https://www7.aeat.es/wlpl/SSII-FACT/ws/fe/SiiFactFEV1SOAP"));
Servicio.Endpoint.Binding = binding;                        

Servicio.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = 
cFunciones.EncontrarCertificado(DatosEnvio.NombreCertificado);
                Servicio.ClientCredentials.UseIdentityConfiguration = true;

Servicio.SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas(GrupoFacturasAEAT.FacturasAltas.Facturas);
```

Hay que crearse una función para el tema del *SSL/TLS*:

```
public static bool ValidateServerCertificate(Object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
   return true;
}
```

---

Ya he conseguido que me envíe sin errores. He añadido las siguientes dos líneas antes de hacer el envío:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate (object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; };
```

Esto obliga a establecer una conexión TLS. También he cambiado la forma en la que informaba del certificado, pues parece ser que a la hora de conectarse no pide las credenciales de forma correcta, así que la contraseña la incluyo en los parámetros para poder autenticar el certificado.

```
string certPath = @"D:\TMP\Certificado.pfx";
string certPass = "clave";
X509Certificate2 certifikat = new X509Certificate2(certPath, certPass, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();                    
binding.Name = "siiBinding";
binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;                    
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;

FacturasEmitidas.siiSOAPClient Servicio = new FacturasEmitidas.siiSOAPClient("SuministroFactEmitidasPruebas", new EndpointAddress("https://www7.aeat.es/wlpl/SSII-FACT/ws/fe/SiiFactFEV1SOAP"));
Servicio.Endpoint.Binding = binding;                                                            
Servicio.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = certifikat;
```